# Problem with MSXML6 classes and properties

Tags: c++, xml, xsd, msxml, msxml6

I am using MSXML6 to validate some XML files against XSD schemas.

According to [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048764/validate-xml-schema-using-msxml-parser) and [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms753815(v=vs.85)), the IXMLDomDocument has a property called schemas that is supposed to allow me to load an xsd file and associate it with my document.

My problem is that on this line : `pXD->schemas = pXS.GetInterfacePtr();`, Visual says that `class "MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocument2" has no member "schemas"`

Here's what my code looks like :

```
...
#import <msxml6.dll>
using namespace MSXML2;
...
bool validate_XML_against_XSD(){
    ...
    IXMLDOMSchemaCollectionPtr   pXS;
    IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr          pXD = NULL;
    MSXML2::IXMLDOMParseErrorPtr pErr = NULL;
    _bstr_t                      strResult = "";

    CComVariant  xsd_file;
    xsd_file = "path_to_xsd";

    BSTR empty_bstr = SysAllocString(L"urn:namespace");

    HRESULT hr = pXS.CreateInstance(__uuidof(XMLSchemaCache60));
    hr = pXS->add(empty_bstr, xsd_file);

    // Create a DOMDocument and set its properties.
    hr = pXD.CreateInstance(__uuidof(DOMDocument60));

    // Assign the schema cache to the DOMDocument's
    // schemas collection.
    pXD->schemas = pXS.GetInterfacePtr();

    // Load books.xml as the DOM document.
    pXD->async = VARIANT_FALSE;
    pXD->validateOnParse = VARIANT_TRUE;
    pXD->resolveExternals = VARIANT_TRUE;
    hr = pXD->load("TheXmlDocument.xml");
    ...
}
```

I also got the same error for :

```
pXD->async = VARIANT_FALSE;
pXD->validateOnParse = VARIANT_TRUE;
pXD->resolveExternals = VARIANT_TRUE;
```

It says that `class "MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocument2" has no member "async"` etc

So, I don't really understand why so much different examples seems to have no problem with this sample of code but I do.

I tried to look for other documentation or stackoverflow posts that would tell me to do an other way but I didn't find any.

Is it a problem of library import or a problem from my code? Anyone has an idea of how to fix this?

Thanks